# How to do Vertical+Horizontal centering in CSS

Tags: css

It regularly occurs that I want to center a css box inside another one both vertically and horizontally.  What's the simplest way to do so that satisfies the following constraints?

- The box should be precisely centered, not approximately.
- The technique should work in modern browsers and in IE versions back to 8
- The technique should **not** depend on explicitly knowing the width or height of either the centered content or the containing box.
- I generally know the container is larger than the content, but supporting larger content (which then overflows symmetrically) would be nice...
- The underlying content of the container must still be able to respond to clicks and hovers except where obscured by the centered content

I currently use 4 (!) nested divs to achieve this, with css along the following lines:

```
.centering-1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.centering-2 { 
    height:100%; 
    display:inline-table; 
}
.centering-3 { 
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
.centering-content { 
    visibility:visible; 
}
```

You can see **[this in action as a jsbin snippet](http://jsbin.com/ofapiv/1/edit)**.
However, this approach, while workable, feels like extreme overkill due to the large number of wrapper divs, and it doesn't work with content that's larger than the container.  How can I center things in CSS?

Comment: Was thinking the same thing.

Comment: If you have set the width and height in percent you could do it quite easily with `position:absolute`. Otherwise you'd have to use jQuery to get the current width, subtract it from the middle position (`left:50%`), and set it to that value

Comment: There are a number of methods for horizontal alignment of stuff even when you don't know the width of the element being centered, but vertical centering an element of unknown height is a lot more tricky.  The `display: table` and `display: table-cell` + `vertical-align: middle` is the simplest and most hassle-free pure CSS method.  You could simplify that CSS/HTML markup some though, no need for like 5 nested divs.  When dealing with unknown dimensions, that's really the main way to do it without resorting to Javascript.

Comment: horizontally, it isn't very difficult, using `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left;` with a parent `div` on full width with `text-align: center` for older versions of IE. I am however puzzled about the vertical centering.

Comment: This question might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you looked into the flexbox model at all?

Comment: @j08691 The OP specifies IE8.  Internet Explorer doesn't support it until version 10.

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchange

Comment: @Ennui my thoughts exactly, hence the question: *how*?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO (and cimmanon): I don't want to have this bit of code reviewed, I want to center vertically+horizontally *without* my code.  Also, given how often I run into variations of this problem, I hope the question's answers will prove useful to others - so I don't think this is a code review.

Comment: Asking for a simpler way of expressing existing, working code is a code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizontal centering is easy:

```
.inner {
  width: 70%; /* Anything less than 100% */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

But vertical centering is a little tricky.  The best technique for modern browsers is to combine inline-block and a pseudo elements. This originates from "Ghost element", the last technique at http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/.  It sets adds a pseudo-element and uses inline-block styles get the centering.
The CSS:

```
.outer { 
  height: 10rem; 
  text-align: center; 
  outline: dotted black 1px; 
}

.outer:before { 
  content: ''; 
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner { 
  width: 10rem; 
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: solid black 1px; 
}
```

An example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/ucwgi

---

For simpler cases, the following may be good options:

For single lines of content, you can do a quick and dirty vertical centering job on the text within an element by using line-height larger than your font-size:

```
.inner { 
  border: 1px solid #666; 
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

The solution with widest support is to use a non-semantic table. This works with very old versions of IE and doesn't require JavaScript:

```
td.inner { 
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

And here is simple solution for known height elements (which could be in `em`s, not `px`):

```
.outer { 
  position:relative; 
}
.inner { 
  position: absolute; 
  top:50%; 
  height:4em; 
  margin-top:-2em; 
  width: 50%; left: 25%; 
}
```

Comment: That ghost element technique sounds *very nice*!

Comment: hmm, however it only works when the `.outer` element has an explicit height; this isn't a big problem since `.outer` can be absolutely positioned to have 100% width/height.  Also, to avoid weird edge cases, it looks like you'd need to add e.g. a max-size to the inner box (and either use `box-sizing` or no border&padding) to ensure that with the container gets smaller than the content you get reasonable behavior instead of completely garbled layout.  Still, this looks really promising!

Comment: Nice bonus: if you leave no spacing between the `outer` and `inner` you don't need to use the hackish `margin-right: 0.25em`

Comment: I like the last bit; but the margin-auto trick relies on further things like `position:absolute;`, and the table requires further work to get horizontal centering (and anyhow that's basically what I mention in the question), so they aren't really complete - could you remove, complete, or deemphasize those - I really love your pointer to the ghost element, but it seems almost like an afterthought here :-)

Comment: I've put your ghost element technique into **[a jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/uqutol/3/edit)** if anyone wants to see how it works out.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne - I've updated my answer with your feedback.  Thanks for the feedback; I didn't really have time to make it super-awesome when I wrote it.

Comment: Oh thanks!  Your answer was helpful as it was, but now it's a lot more approachable for people that aren't willing to read the whole thing :-)

Comment: There is one last issue: as with many `inline-block` tricks, it's important that there is no space between the opening tags of `.outer` and `.inner` otherwise the horizontal centering will be slightly off.  Your codepen example exhibits that assymetry; try making the column almost as small as `.inner` to see it.  It's a mistake that's easy to make, so it bears mentioning.  Oh, and there's no need for padding on `.outer`.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne - Ah yes, the white space!  Good call, thanks!  I added the top and bottom padding to account for when `.inner` was bigger than `.outer`, but I think I'll break that out into a separate example.

Comment: I've experimented with this approach, but I've never really found a *nice* solution when that (inner bigger than outer) happens.  Maybe giving outer large negative margins (or filling the real outer with an intermediate that has them) can sort of mitigate the situation, but it ain't pretty.  Still, I'm really happy with this as it is :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can get by with 2 fewer elements.  Anything less than this is going to require things that IE8 (and IE9) doesn't support.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/0ltap96z

```
  <div class="centering-1">
    <div class="centering-2">
      <div class="intrinsically-sized-box">
        <p>You can put any content here too and the box will auto-size.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {max-width:750px;}
.generalblock {
  margin-top:2em; 
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  border:20px solid cyan;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.centering-1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  visibility:hidden;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.centering-2 {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.intrinsically-sized-box {
  visibility:visible;
  max-width:300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow; 
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do vertical centering, at least, chrome + FF show the yellow box at the top of the container.