# Chrome/Safari css issue with visibility + overflow

Tags: css, webkit

I have a block with `visibility: visible; overflow: hidden;` inside a element that's `visibility: hidden`.  In IE/FF this works as expected, the inner content is shown and clickable, but the container is not.  However, in webkit browsers such as Chrome+Safari, the content is not shown.

Is this a webkit bug (if so, which one?), and how can I work around it?

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/egikap/1/edit

**Edit:** The CSS2.1 spec has [this to say on `visibility: hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility):

> #### 11.2 Visibility: the `visibility` property
>
> *[...]*
>
> **hidden**
>
> The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have `visibility: visible`.

Comment: I gave the innerblock position absolute and was able to see it

Comment: I don't really get the point of having an invisible parent here ? By the way, like @wilsonrufus said, giving an absolute or even relative position to the `.roundVisible` class make it work.

Comment: Hmm, never know that this is possible. Do you you know where this is behaviour specified, In the specs i neither can see that it works that way nor that it should not? And to @Brewal for styling this could be indeed helpful.

Comment: @Brewal: the point of having a `hidden` parent is that the parent's rectangular region will otherwise obscure the content below, making it unclickable and unhoverable.   In particular, if there are many visible inner blocks or they are (like in the example) not the same shape as the invisible rectangle, if you make the parent `visible`, you can't click on the background where the transparent square covers it, even though the circular shape suggests you could.  It's more annoying once you start pushing around the circle, because then the unclickable region may be in a surprising spot.

Comment: @Brewal: `position: relative` sounds like an answer to me - if you write it up!

Comment: Is the text is the circle supposed to be vertically in the middle? Because if you have a wider font, such as Verdana, the text is two lines and is no longer in the middle.

Comment: @Mr Lister: good question!  This is just an example; for this question I really only care about making sure the popover circle is visible and does not obscure any unrelated bits of the page.  In actual fact, the circle won't be displaying this kind of freeform text (which would look weird, right?), and I asked a separate question on how to  achieve vertical+horizontal centering on SO just recently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368244/how-to-do-verticalhorizontal-centering-in-css).