# Text Disappears after page scroll and toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw a good website template and started making a website. The link is: https://html5up.net/lens. In the process, I observed a typical UI bug, where in if a user scrolls down the page and clicks on "X" of the image (to see fullscreen image),toggles back, scrolls to the top of the page, the content which was visible before disappears though it still appears in the DOM. 
I saw the js function written for the toggle, it's straightforward and works fine until we don't scroll on the web page. Please see bug screenshot.[Screenshot of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm0zi.jpg)

Comment: It looks like something is causing it to not redraw. Highlight the text and it re-apears. So it may be just waiting for focus or something. Would have to see the code.

Comment: No issues in firefox. In chrome it does goes blank and then reappears. Its as if it is trying to reload an image. Perhaps using smaller thumbnails in the scroll bar instead of full size images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known, ongoing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568673/is-there-a-bug-in-chromes-css-visibility-rendering) with [Chrome and CSS visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401007/chrome-safari-css-issue-with-visibility-overflow). You can 'fix' this by updating the CSS of the affected children, ie. changing classes or simply setting the visibility of the child element manually. I believe this to be because Chrome automatically prevents the rendering of the divs because at the time they are called to be shown, they are off screen and not viewable.