# Vertically center an image using CSS on firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, vertical-alignment

I want to display a banner in the vertical middle of my page using HTML/CSS but I have not be able to do it so far.The image is always on top of my window.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<head>
    <title>Bo-bee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
        <img class="banner" src="./res/pictures/logo-bee.png" alt="bobee banner"/>
</body>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.banner{
    width:100%;
}
img{
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Note: I'm using firefox 22.0.
Kind regargs.

Comment: Your image is a fixed height correct?

Comment: If your `<img>` is of a fixed width and height you can use absolute positioning and negative margins to position an element vertically and horizontally. Not the most modern technique, but it works decently across all browsers.

Comment: I don't know if it is a good practice but no, my image hasn't fixed size. I just want to do a banner which is center in the vertical middle of the screen which fill all the width of the screen in the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do Vertical+Horizontal centering in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368244/how-to-do-verticalhorizontal-centering-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align` is used for `inline` or `table-cell` elements, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align.

So let's use the CSS `display` property values of `table` and `table-cell`.  `display: table;` needs to be applied to the parent element for `display: table-cell` to work. http://caniuse.com/css-table

http://jsfiddle.net/uhqMw/1/

*CSS*

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body {
     display: table;
     background-color: blue;
}
.banner {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
     width: 100%;
}
```

*HTML*

```html
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100/" />
</div>
```

Comment: I want my image to fill the entire screen on width. So I'm setting the width at 100% of the size available. Doing so the image is resizing itself to an unknown size(the height). If I understand correctly I can't put margin-top to a correct value because this value is unknown isn't it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`.

Comment: Thanks it was the solution. I will try to understand how it works now.

Comment: We are mimicking how a table displays content by default.  Which is vertically centering it's content.  An image will scale proportionally if it can.  By setting it's width to 100% it will take up the full width of it's containing element (which is 100% the browser width) and the height will take care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

from: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

CSS level 2 doesn't have a property for centering things vertically. There will probably be one in CSS level 3. But even in CSS2 you can center blocks vertically, by combining a few properties. The trick is to specify that the outer block is to be formatted as a table cell, because the contents of a table cell can be centered vertically.

The example below centers a paragraph inside a block that has a certain given height. A separate example shows a paragraph that is centered vertically in the browser window, because it is inside a block that is absolutely positioned and as tall as the window.

```
DIV.container {
    min-height: 10em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle }
...
<DIV class="container">
  <P>This small paragraph...
</DIV>
```

[Example with image here](http://jsfiddle.net/UHMcr/)

Comment: Using this solution it means that I have to fix a minimal size for my div. Doing so there will be some displays issues on certain screens isn't it ?

Comment: No, I don't think you have to select a minimum size, I did so to make sure there was enough space to actually center something.

Comment: Helas, if I remove the min-height field or trying to replace it by height:100%; it doesn't work anymore.Maybe I should try to use some JS to do it.

Comment: That's because the `html` and `body` elements aren't 100% screen height yet.  have a look at hungerstar's answer for detail.

Answer (score 0):

can you the fallowing code,this might be useful

```
    div {position:relative;}
    img {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;}
    .image {min-height:50px}
```

if it not works,please check 
     [this](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html) link

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

put the img inside a div and then give the div a class of banner

set the banner width to 100% and the the image to width 100% so it fills the div container for the banner

html:

```
<title>Bo-bee</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner"
<img src="../res/pictures/logo-bee.png" alt="bobee banner"/>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
   .banner{
     width:100%;
     margin:0 auto;
    }

   .banner img{
    width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already did this. It solve my problem for the width. But my main problem is to center the image vertically at the same time as the width is 100%...

Answer (score 0):

It's just:

```
background-position: center;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position